# Make div auto resize to fit its container height

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="banner"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These `div`s are auto resize base on its content with `overflow: auto`. Now I'm facing a problem. When `div:content` overflow its parent, `div: right` and `div: container` will resize to fit with `div:content` height. But `div: left` height stay unchange. How to make `div: left` height auto resize to fit `div: container` when its height change?

Here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/cDqSj/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.left {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.right {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 260px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/cDqSj/3/)

Hope I understood the question corectly - now works fine, if you try changing content height.